# WordPress 2.9.2 VS WordPress 3.0 Release Candidate

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm going to do a  new install of Wordpress. new 3.0 version is coming. current stable version is "WordPress 2.9.2" and "WordPress 3.0 Release Candidate" the last release before final version 3.

So for now i should setup 2.9.2 or 3.0 Release Candidate?

will i have to replace all files to RC upon final release?

What are cons to use Release Candidate version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have reached RC2 and there are usually only two release candidates, you could wait for the final version to come out within the next week (or at max 2).

But also installing the RC2 is OK, I am using WordPress since Version 2.7.1 and there was never a issue updating it to the newest version. Just backup your database in case anything goes wrong. But usually nothing goes really wrong. Just run the automatically update and you should be fine.

Comment: and where is official announcement for RC2 http://wordpress.org/development/2010/05/wordpress-3-0-release-candidate/

Comment: They haven't annouced it yet. But it is available and you can download it here: http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.0-RC2.zip. There are also only 16 Tickets left, so the final version will be available very soon: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/milestone/3.0. I would agree with Oli's statement about your release date of the blog. If you want to publish it right now, you should use WP 2.9.2. and then use the update function as soon as WP 3 is out. If you are going to release it in two weeks you should take the chance to get familiar with WP3 before launching your blog.

Answer (score 1):

It's not stable. There are likely bugs that may spoil or impede your progress with it. There may be security issues. There will likely be problems with certain plugins that are only maintained up to 2.9.*.

If you're comfortable navigating [their bug tracker](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/) and you're unlikely to take this site live before the final release is made, by all means, suck it and see.

But if this is something you want to launch tomorrow and you need it to work, go with stable. If it's any consolation, the update process is pretty robust.

The fact that they're some months behind their original roadmap might be cause for concern.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will go for 2.9.2.